# If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, not necessarily independent, show that $cov(X+Y,X-Y)=0$

Tags: probability

The answer wrote, $$cov(X+Y,X-Y) = cov(X,X) + cov (X,-Y)+cov(Y,X)+cov(Y,-Y)$$

Can anyone enlighten me on this, which formula did they use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the bilinearity of covariance, we find 
$$\begin{align}\text{Cov}(X+Y,X-Y) & =\text{Cov}(X,X-Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,X-Y)\\
&=\text{Cov}(X,X)-\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,X)-\text{Cov}(Y,Y)\\
&=\text{Var}(X)-\text{Var}(Y) = 0
\end{align}$$
where the last equality follows from $X$ and $Y$ being identically distributed.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{Var}}$

Covariance is bilinear. You can read more about the [covariance properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Properties) on the Wikipedia page. Three relevant points from there are, for constants $a,b,c,d$ and real-valued random variables $X, Y, W$ and $V$, we have

1. $\cov (X,X) = \var(X)$
2. $\cov(aX,bY) = ab\cov(X,Y)$
3. $\cov(aX+bY, cW+dV) = ac\cov(X,W)+ad\cov(X,V)+bc\cov(Y,W)+bd\cov(Y,V)$

Those are the formulas you use to get that step and then to compelete the problem.